# can a power mosfet driver be used 'standalone'?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

TI has the [UCCx732x series power mosfet driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27324.pdf). It's capable of 4A, with obvious thermal caveats.

If my power needs are below 4A, can I use this driver chip directly? Is there a downside of doing so?

Comment: The "4A" figure is misleading. It can briefly drive that current into a short circuit. Have a look at the output resistance figures in the datasheet if you're not using it with a capacitive load.

Comment: aha, thanks @AbeKarplus. Feel free to place that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It's like when you see an op-amp with a 50MV/s slew rate and go "wow, that's a high voltage". (50MV/s is better interpreted as 5V/100ns in this context)

Comment: @immibis. That's why marketing works so well. You juggle the numbers vs. time and make the boring look amazing.

Comment: I've used a dual gate driver to run a Dickson multiplier when I wanted 40v on a 5v/12v board. Note the time limit for your 4A specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the datasheet for your MOSFET driver. I would suggest NOT using this IC to directly drive a transformer. If you do you must use series capacitor, polypropylene 100 nF rated for 50 volts, to block any DC currents. It might work ok, but no serious engineer would back up that design.

> Analog input voltage (INA, INB) –0.3 to VDD + 0.3 V not to exceed 16 V
>
> Output body diode DC current (OUTA, OUTB) 0.2 A OUT_DC
>
> ***Output current (OUTA, OUTB) DC 0.2 A***
>
> ***Output current (OUTA, OUTB) Pulsed (0.5 µs) 4.5 A***
>
> Output voltage (OUTA, OUTB) 16 V

This is quoted from this source: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27324.pdf